# Set the default value of a Facebook Registration Plugin "Text Field"

Tags: facebook, plugins, field, default, registration

Good afternoon,

I'm now use the Registration plugin of Facebook and I would to set the default value of a field in text type.

But I don't know if it's possible ? How to set a default value of a text field in PHP and in the plugin ? Thank's for your Help !

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
         client_id=APP_ID&
         redirect_uri=[...]&
         fields=[{'name':'name'},
                {'name':'last_name'},
                {'name':'first_name'},
                {'name':'birthday'},
                {'name':'gender'},
                {'name':'email'},
                {'name':'telephone', 'description':'T\u00e9l\u00e9phone', 'type':'text', 'default':'sith'},
                {'name':'portable', 'description':'Portable (facultatif)', 'type':'text','no_submit':true},
                {'name':'fax', 'description':'Fax (facultatif)', 'type':'text','no_submit':true},
                {'name':'adresse','description':'Adresse','type':'text','default':'truc'},
                {'name':'adresse_suite','description':'Adresse (suite)','type':'text','no_submit':true},
                {'name':'code_postal','description':'Code postal','type':'text'},
                {'name':'ville','description':'Ville','type':'text'},
                {'name':'pays','description':'Pays','type':'select',
                'options':[...]},
                {'name':'password'},
                {'name':'captcha'},
                {'name':'abonnement','description':'Re\u00e7evoir la Newsletter','type':'checkbox'},
                {'name':'stop_pub','description':'Re\u00e7evoir des offres marketing et bons d\'achat','type':'checkbox'},
                {'name':'offre_sortir','description':'Re\u00e7evoir des bons plans Sortir Malin dans votre r\u00e9gion','type':'checkbox'},
                {'name':'offre_partenaire','description':'Offres publicitaires de la part d\'autres partenaires','type':'checkbox'}]"
            scrolling="auto"
            frameborder="no"
            style="border:none"
            allowTransparency="true"
            width="100%"
            height="850"
            onvalidate="validate">
    </iframe>
```

Sorry for my bad English, I'm French ! =)

Comment: Is there something wrong with this iframe code, or are you asking how to add dynamic content to it?

Comment: I just asking how to add dynamic content to it by PHP, and to make it optionnal (for the "fax" or "mobile phone" fields for example) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/), the `default` parameter is only applicable to the `type:select` and `type:checkbox` fields, not the text fields ): So you're kinda screwed there.

For reference:
[default only applies to select and checkbox fields http://o7.no/K5jDj0](http://o7.no/K5jDj0)

However, if it were me, I'd build a complete array of the options I wanted to send, and `json_encode` them in one go instead of defining them directly inside the `<iframe>` tag, for example:

```
<?php
$regOptions = array(
    array('name' => 'name'),
    array('name' => 'last_name'),
    array('name' => 'birthday'),
    //the other fields
    array('name' => 'telephone',
          'description' => 'T\u00e9l\u00e9phone',
          'type' => 'text'
    ),
    //the other fields  
);
?>

//Then in your iframe:
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
     client_id=APP_ID&
     redirect_uri=[...]&

     fields="<?= urlencode(json_encode($regOptiosn)); ?>

     scrolling="auto"
     frameborder="no"
     style="border:none"
     allowTransparency="true"
     width="100%"
     height="850"
     onvalidate="validate">
</iframe>
```

This allows you to leverage `json_encode` and `urlencode` to define your fields without fear of the browser mucking up the request due to wonky strings.

As for some fields being optional, required, check out the [advaned registration button features](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/) in the doucmentation. FB affords you a few ways to validate your form, which should allow you to block form submission when fields are invalid/not filled out.

Comment: It's true that it's more appropriate to make it in PHP and to encode it before to send it to the view. I've follow your second option but i've always the same problem. I can't define a default value to my input text =( . The 'default' attribute doesn't work. My code here : http://vpaste.net/JTmXH

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've found a solution : separate my form completion in two steps : One with the basics infos, name, email ... and another step with the complementary info like telephone number ... See you soon ! ;)